# How to kill a container using kubernetes API?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go, e2e

I am trying to kill a container using client-go and [e2e](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/e2e-framework/blob/1af0fd64ebd2474f40cbb1a29c8997ed56aba89d/klient/k8s/resources/resources.go#L293) framework in Golang but not able to do it successfully.
Example of the full implementation can be accessed [e2e](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/e2e-framework/tree/1af0fd64ebd2474f40cbb1a29c8997ed56aba89d/examples/pod_exec) apart from this I am using kind image as "kindest/node:v1.26.6"

I have tried the following commands but none using the following pieces of code.

```
args := []string{"kill", "1"}
var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
err := cfg.Client().Resources().ExecInPod(ctx, namespace, podName, containerName, args, &stdout, &stderr)
```

```
args = []string{"/bin/sh", "-c", "'kill", "1'"}
err = cfg.Client().Resources().ExecInPod(ctx, namespace, podName, containerName, args, &stdout, &stderr)
```

```
args = []string{"/bin/sh", "-c", "\"kill 1\""}
err = cfg.Client().Resources().ExecInPod(ctx, namespace, podName, containerName, args, &stdout, &stderr)
```

But all of them are giving error. Some are giving

exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "kill": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

while some are giving

"command terminated with exit code 127" or
"command terminated with exit code 2"

I have also tried the following and it is working but in this case I have a dependency on kubectl which I want to avoid.

```
cmdString := fmt.Sprintf("/c kubectl exec -it %s -n %s -c %s -- bash -c 'kill 1'", podName, namespace, containerName)
    args := strings.Split(cmdString, " ")
    cmd := exec.Command("powershell", args...)
    err := cmd.Run()
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- code that we can compile and run locally to reproduce the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: Hey, [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/e2e-framework/tree/1af0fd64ebd2474f40cbb1a29c8997ed56aba89d/examples/pod_exec) contains the example that can be reproduced. However I am using ```kind image as "kindest/node:v1.26.6" ``` and you can use the above args to test it in your system

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt looks okay at first glance, although I don't see an `ExecInPod` method in the `client-go` package. Because you haven't provided a reproducible example I haven't tried building and running your code.

There's no guarantee that the `kill` command is available inside a particular container. If you update your question to include details about your deployment manifests -- so we can see what image you're using -- we can provide you with a better answer.

---

Your second two examples are simply invalid:

### 1

```
args = []string{"/bin/sh", "-c", "'kill", "1'"}
```

Here you're trying to run the command `'kill`, which doesn't exist. You need to pass a single string to `sh -c`, so this would need to look like:

```
args = []string{"/bin/sh", "-c", "kill 1"}
```

The argument to `-c` is the script to run; any additional parameters are provided as arguments to that script (so in this example, the shell would see `1'` in `$0`).

You could avoid the shell altogether and just run:

```
args = []string{"kill", "1"}
```

But again, both of these solutions require that the target container have the `kill` command available.

### 2

```
args = []string{"/bin/sh", "-c", "\"kill 1\""}
```

Here you're trying to run the command `"kill 1"`, which against doesn't exist; if you were to run this from the command line you would see:

```
$ "kill 1"
bash: kill 1: command not found...
```

The correct syntax would be as shown in the previous section.

Comment: ExecInPod is included in [e2e package](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/e2e-framework/blob/1af0fd64ebd2474f40cbb1a29c8997ed56aba89d/klient/k8s/resources/resources.go#L293) and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/e2e-framework/blob/1af0fd64ebd2474f40cbb1a29c8997ed56aba89d/examples/pod_exec/envtest_test.go#L71) is one of the examples of how to use it. Let me know if you need something else

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's generally not possible to kill a container from within a container. That's because PID 1 inside container ignores any signal.

From [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground):

> A process running as PID 1 inside a container is treated specially by
> Linux: it ignores any signal with the default action. As a result, the
> process will not terminate on SIGINT or SIGTERM unless it is coded to
> do so.

Instead you should rely on `kubectl delete pod` functionality.